# How do I calculate if this data fits a bivariate normal distribution?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution

This might be a very basic question and I might have a fundamental misunderstanding of the concepts but I hope to test to see if some xy data fits a bivariate normal distribution and I don't know if there is a way to do this easily in Excel (or produce a 3D representation of it). When plotted on a scatter graph, there seems to be an increase in density of points towards a specific place, and I want to see if it is significant.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/sRXZBAsu) is the data in question.

For context, I am a geologist and this is data from a stereographic projection of poles to planes of dipping vesicles in a pyroclastic flow that I recently measured in the field.

Comment: The inconsistency between fitting a bivariate normal--which *necessarily* has a maximum density at a specific location--and wanting to see whether this is "significant"--suggest that you edit your post to explain your objectives in your own terms, rather than using statistical terms that might be miscommunicating.  What is your research question?  What are the raw data?  What do they represent?  How were they measured?