# How to test whether each sample is generated from bivariate gaussian distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, inference

[image: A sample datum that suspectedly comes from gaussian distribution. Color shows its density in each position]

I have dataset that each samples has its frequency along x and y axis. A sample can be visaulized as above. Each sample can be thought as an image which has only one channel.

Each image has central point which can be thought has mode(or mean, if it is from gaussian) in distribution.

Another sample may have one mode or not, and may come from other than gaussian distribution.

So, my question is as follows.

**How can I know whether each sample came from gaussian distribution?**

Comment: Let me clarify: Is a sample for you a collection of datapoints and the image you have drawn above is then a histogram over these datapoints or does a sample consist of this image itself (without any data that produced this image)? In the first case you could just form the likelihood and 'predict' that it is a 2-d Gaussian is the likelihood exceeds a certain threshold. In the second case you need to bin the image in some sense and select a data point $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ in each bin and then form something like $\sum_i p_{\mu, \Sigma}(x_i, y_i) - z_i$ and minimze that in $\mu$ and $\Sigma$...

Comment: plug this into the expression one last time and then predict that it comes from a Gaussian is that expression is lower than a certain threshold...

The optimal threshold could be found using a ROC curve.

Comment: This question was asked (but not answered) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153439.  It was partially answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161687.  By coupling that answer with tests of univariate Normality you will have a good procedure.

Comment: Just to clarify, every sample is 2-dimensional image. Some sample looks like its data generating process is bivariate gaussian, and some looks like its from uniform distribution along x and y axis each, and others looks like its from some random distribution.

Comment: But as each sample's number of data points differ, I guess it's inappropriate to calculate likelihoods and compare.